# Why can't I create a method in my main method?

Tags: java, methods

I tried creating a method within my `main` method, and I cannot find out what the problem is.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static void menu()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you can't create a method inside a method.

Comment: C-based compiled languages generally don't allow you to nest methods like that.  Algol-based languages (Pascal, Ada) do allow this.  Just the language designers' choice.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to create a method that accesses another method's local variables, you can do it with a local class:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    int i = args.length;

    final int finalI = i;
    class Inner {
        void dumpit() {
            System.out.println(finalI);
        }
    }
    new Inner().dumpit();
}
```

This is a contrived example, of course.  Note that the inner class can only use `final` local variables declared in the method.  This means that any variables you use have to have their values fixed at or before the point the inner class is declared, and it means that the  inner method can't change any local variables in the outer method (but you could wrap variables in some other object and modify them there, since only the reference to the object needs to be `final`).  Because of all this, there probably is no good use of the above idiom.  There should always be a better way to write it.  But I wanted to mention it in case there's some good use for it.  The more likely use of a local class would be to write a class that implements some interface or extends some other class (e.g. `Runnable` or `Thread`), then create an instance of the local class that is then passed to some other method.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class test {
    // Define the menu method in the class not in another method.
    public static void menu()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu(); // Call it from the main method.
    }
}
```